# Discord.js Event only working once after running it

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have an **event handler that works only once** when I execute my bot. This **should block any website link into a specific channel** and send the message.content into another channel where links are allowed, but this **works only on the first time that someone send a link** into my Guild(server).

Obs: I have an event/command handler into the index file.

Is there any way to fix this and block the links every time?

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'message',
    execute(message) {
        console.log('\x1b[31m', `${message.author.tag}`,'\x1b[0m', `in`, '\x1b[34m', `#${message.channel.name}: `, '\x1b[33m', `${message.content}`, '\x1b[0m');
        
        //bloquear links
        if (message.channel.id === 'CHANNELID'){
        function is_url(str) {
            const regexp = /^(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\.254|192\.168)(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/\S*)?$/;
            if(regexp.test(str)) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }                    
                }
                if(is_url(message.content) === true) {
                    message.delete()
                    message.channel.id ="CHANNELID"
                    message.reply(`You can not send link here! \n${message.content}`)
                }
            }
    },
};


/*This is my Event handler into index file
const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync('./events').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

    for (const file of eventFiles) {
const event = require(`./events/${file}`);
    if (event.once) {
        client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args, client));
        } else {
        client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args, client));
        }
    }*/
```

Comment: Does the Message event still emit afterwards?

Comment: Yes, I don't get any error and everything else works fine

Comment: Reverted to revision one, as the edit added code that was not present in the original post.

Comment: Is your message handler possibly getting added with `client.once` instead of `client.on`?

Comment: I've tried to use only `client.on` and also inside of `client.on('message', message => {` into the index file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that `message.channel.id ="CHANNELID"` was causing this issue.  I removed this line and `message.reply` line for now.